# Cluster point and Limit Point

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence and let $S(a_n)$ be the collection of all limit points of convergent subsequences of $(a_n)$. Show that if c is a cluster point of $S(a_n)$, then $c \in S(a_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $c$ is a cluster point, you can always construct a sequence converging to $c$.